# XML - How Can I Add a Second Entry?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd, w3c, w3c-validation

I want to try and add a second entry to my XML file, however, upon adding another entry I get an error on the validator

**Code:**
Here is my DTD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE car [

    <!ELEMENT car (make, model, year, colour, engine, accessories)>

    <!ELEMENT make (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT colour (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT engine (number_of_cylinders, fuel_system)>
    <!ELEMENT number_of_cylinders (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT fuel_system (#PCDATA|carburetted|fueld-injected)*>
    <!ELEMENT accessories EMPTY>
        <!ATTLIST accessories radio (yes|no) #REQUIRED>
        <!ATTLIST accessories air_conditioning (yes|no) #REQUIRED>
        <!ATTLIST accessories power_steering (yes|no) #REQUIRED>
]>
```

XML Entry:

```
<car>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>001</model>
    <year>2014</year>
    <colour>black</colour>
    <engine> <number_of_cylinders>3</number_of_cylinders> <fuel_system>"carburetted"</fuel_system></engine>
    <accessories radio="yes" air_conditioning="yes" power_steering="yes"/>
</car>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only allowed to have one root element, so you're going to need to add another element that can contain multiple `car` elements.

Something like:

```
<!ELEMENT cars (car+)>
```

I noticed a couple of other things too.

1. It seems like you're confusing [internal and external subsets](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd). You're not allowed to have a doctype declaration in an external subset. In the example you gave that should all be one file. If the DTD is in a separate file, move the doctype declaration from the DTD to the XML instance and reference the DTD.
2. You can simplify your attribute declarations by only using 1 per element.
3. You reference the elements `carburetted` and `fueld-injected`, but don't declare them. It looks like you actually want the option of 2 values. You can't do that with DTD so you'll have to make an attribute with the enumerations.

Here are a couple of examples that show:

- the internal subset
- the external subset
- the extra element references converted to `type` attribute
- the attribute declaration simplification
- the addition of the `cars` element

## Internal Subset Example

### cars.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE cars [

<!ELEMENT cars (car+)>

<!ELEMENT car (make, model, year, colour, engine, accessories)>

<!ELEMENT make (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT colour (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT engine (number_of_cylinders, fuel_system)>
<!ELEMENT number_of_cylinders (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT fuel_system EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST fuel_system
          type (carburetted|fuel-injected) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT accessories EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST accessories 
          radio            (yes|no) #REQUIRED
          air_conditioning (yes|no) #REQUIRED
          power_steering   (yes|no) #REQUIRED>
]>
<cars>
    <car>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>001</model>
        <year>2014</year>
        <colour>black</colour>
        <engine> 
            <number_of_cylinders>3</number_of_cylinders> 
            <fuel_system type="carburetted"/>
        </engine>
        <accessories radio="yes" air_conditioning="yes" power_steering="yes"/>
    </car>
</cars>
```

## External Subset Example

### cars.dtd

```
<!ELEMENT cars (car+)>

<!ELEMENT car (make, model, year, colour, engine, accessories)>

<!ELEMENT make (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT colour (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT engine (number_of_cylinders, fuel_system)>
<!ELEMENT number_of_cylinders (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT fuel_system EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST fuel_system
          type (carburetted|fuel-injected) #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT accessories EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST accessories 
          radio            (yes|no) #REQUIRED
          air_conditioning (yes|no) #REQUIRED
          power_steering   (yes|no) #REQUIRED>
```

### cars.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE cars SYSTEM "cars.dtd">
<cars>
    <car>
        <make>Ford</make>
        <model>001</model>
        <year>2014</year>
        <colour>black</colour>
        <engine> 
            <number_of_cylinders>3</number_of_cylinders> 
            <fuel_system type="carburetted"/>
        </engine>
        <accessories radio="yes" air_conditioning="yes" power_steering="yes"/>
    </car>
</cars>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to add another car, then your definition needs changing. I suggest that the root be cars and that you locate your car elements within that. the DTD will need amending to specify how many child elements cars is to contain. See http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_elements.asp.